# jQuery Ajax Request Based on Checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

Me again,

Trying to learn some jQuery stuff. Now I'm building an AJAX search engine. AJAX request should depend on the checkboxes values.

I have multiple groups of checkboxes: band[], genere[] and type[]. However I'm stuck with sending proper AJAX request to the PHP script.

My code:

```
$("input.filter").click(function() {        
    if( $("input.filter:checked").length )
        sendRequest('type=ajax&target=display&' + $("input.filter").serialize());
    else
        sendRequest('type=ajax&default=true&target=display')
});
```

Issue: It's not working on checking ant checkbox, it works when the second checkbox is selected or when checkbox is unchecked. Generally, very buggy.

Can anybody provide suggestions or proper function name that can help me solve this issue?

My checkboxes looks like this one:
`<input type="checkbox" name="band[]" class="filter" value="blind guardian" />`

Comment: How about using .change() instead of .click(). Try that out and see i that works any better

Comment: It works fine for me in Chrome, can you provide more sample code so we can see what you have and why it isnt working? http://jsfiddle.net/nJxmN/

Comment: @Matt .change() is not working at all. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Which browser are you testing this in?

Comment: Can plz you provide a semple code of your checkboxes, just to be sure the problem is not with them?

Comment: @josh.trow Weird as it's working for me in both browsers but my code is not.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if the problem is `name="band[]"`. You should NOT be using `[]` as it has special meaning in javascript. Why can't you just use `band`? EDIT: http://jsfiddle.net/nJxmN/1/

Comment: @josh.trow square brackets are needed for multiselect, it is good that way

Comment: @inti hmm...I've seen it go south many times, but I am not a jquery/html expert. I think we need more code.

Comment: What is the main problem, you experience: a) click handler won't fire? b) serialize create bad data? c) bad ajax response?

Comment: @inti - A silly checkbox styling plugin was used, it was causing this issue. Thanks for help everybody!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The square brackets `[]` are needed for multiselect, it is good that way.

Your serialized string should be working server side, like an array:

```
key[]=A&key[]=B&key[]=C
```

would be:

```
Array (
    0 => "A",
    1 => "B",
    2 => "C"
)
```

There must be something else, if it does not work. 
What is the main problem, you experience:

- click handler won't fire?
- serialize create bad data?
- bad ajax response?